# Disable react-jsx per file in a ReasonReact project

Tags: bucklescript, reason-react, rescript

Is there a way to disable react-jsx transformation in some files of a ReasonReact project?

I think the other way around is possible by not adding `"reason": { "react-jsx": 3 }` to `bsconfig.json` and by adding `@@bs.config({jsx: 3})` to the top of the files where you want react-jsx transformation, but that would force me to add this annotation in too many files.

I'd like to build a small DSL based on JSX in a few files while benefiting from React in the rest of my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note: the solution suggested is not very straight forward, and I think it's much simpler to add `@@bs.config` annotations explicitly in all required files, but if you really don't want to do that, the following might work.*

If I'm reading [the compiler code](https://github.com/rescript-lang/rescript-compiler/blob/72a7bf50b689092489203d5855a08aae7c434d1f/jscomp/core/js_implementation.ml#L207-L208) correctly, user-defined ppxs are applied before ReasonReact ppx. In the linked compiler module, `Cmd_ppx_apply.apply_rewriters` will apply with all arguments passed with `-ppx` flag, and `Ppx_entry.rewrite_implementation` is ReasonReact ppx.

Assuming that's true, one could have a ppx that checks a top-level statement like `@@custom.jsx` at the top of the file, that the ppx would check. The ReasonReact ppx [used to have a similar check](https://github.com/rescript-lang/rescript-compiler/blob/90089e386d6b30262291600232f8e16f6a555fd5/jscomp/syntax/reactjs_jsx_ppx.cppo.ml#L983-L1053), in case it serves as reference.

Then if this statement is found, the custom ppx would process the nodes that have the `@JSX` attributes and make sure it removes the attributes from them, so when the compiler passes the AST to ReasonReact ppx, it won't see them.

Note this would break if the ReScript ppx pipeline is updated one day to a driver-based one (unlikely I'd say because that would mean ReScript should support native libraries as 1st class citizens somehow), or if the ordering that was mentioned above changes (ReasonReact ppx applies before user-defined ones).

Comment: hmm interesting, it's a bit too much overhead for my use case, but definitely good to know there's a workaround when really needed!

Comment: Rescript maintainers confirmed disabling the transformation is not possible per file anyway, so your solution or adding `@@bs.config` on top of every other files are the only workarounds we have so far: https://forum.rescript-lang.org/t/disable-react-jsx-per-file/200/6?u=tsnobip